# Android Application To Execute Shell and Prints Output

Tags: java, android, bash, shell

I've been working with scripting languages for some time now, and I am looking to dive into the realm of Android development. I have a base application set up, however I am having trouble executing a shell script(*bash*) and displaying the output to the main window.

This will be a small application, seeing as it's only purpose will be to display and run a shell script. To shorten my question, I want to know how I would create an Android application that and executes a script, (*and displays the output*), such as this:

```
 #This is merely a test
list=ls
echo $list
$list
```

*NOTE: I do know Java, however I am not experienced with Java swing, and/or the arguments required for Android compiling.*

Comment: Android does not use Swing but rather its own original UI framework.  Running shell scripts is *possible* but *unusual* - for one Android's `toolbox` shell is a bit more primitive than `bash`.  If you really want to run a shell and display the output, look at how terminal emulator apps work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be reviewing a few open source tonight.